# PHP PDO: multiple prepared statements using same connection

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to use several prepared statements within a loop on the same connection like so:

```
if (count($deleted) > 0) {
  $stmt_stock = $>conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `stock` 
     . (timestamp, id, qty) VALUES (' . $this->timestamp . ', ?, 0)');
  $stmt_stock->bindParam(1, $id);

  $stmt_status = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `status` '
     . '(timestamp, prev_timestamp, id) VALUES ('
     . $this->timestamp . ', ?, ?)');
  $stmt_status->bindParam(1, $o_ts);
  $stmt_status->bindParam(2, $id);

  $stmt_list = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM `display_list` WHERE `id` = ?');
  $stmt_list->bindParam(1, $id);

  foreach($deleted as $id => $r) {  # $r is here values from $deleted
    $o_ts = $r[0];
    $stmt_stock->execute();
    $stmt_status->execute();
    $stmt_list->execute();
  }
}
```

This ends up only executing `$stmt_status`. However, if I comment out `$stmt_list->execute();` from the `foreach` loop, then both prepared `INSERT` statements work as intended. Why does the loop fail when adding the prepared `DELETE` statement to this loop, and what is the better way to get around this problem?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled (`error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in your `php.ini` file)? Is PDO set to throw exceptions (`$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`)?

Comment: Also, you should bind `timestamp` as well

Comment: Ah, your first query contains a `.` where it shouldn't (just before ` (timestamp, id, qty)`)

Comment: bindParam in loop.